# add client to mrtg

Tags: snmp

i have ubuntu server 20.04 LTS and i want to monitor a few other machines (Linux) via mrtg. I have installed mrtg in the ubuntu server by following [MRTG+Ubuntu](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-mrtg-in-ubuntu) and i can see the traffic for the ethernet port of the localhost. So far so good. I would like to add remote machines (Ubuntu & Raspberrys) and i am stuck on what to do in the clients and at the server. Also, apart from the ethernet interface i would like to add CPU and RAM for each device.

Answer (score -1):

i have managed to create it by adding different files for each device and include them in /etc/mrtg.cfg